# Is there a word for irrational doubt or lack of confidence?

Tags: single-word-requests

A sample sentence would be:

> I have this lingering feeling of **[irrational doubt]** that's discouraging me from pursuing my goals.

I've used Merriam Webster to search for synonyms for doubt but none appeared to be what I was looking for which are distrust, distrustfulness, dubiety, dubitation [archaic], incertitude, misdoubt, misgiving, mistrust, mistrustfulness, query, reservation, skepticism, suspicion, uncertainty. None of which includes the irrational part to it.

Compound word or phrase can be acceptable.

Comment: What do you mean by *irrational doubt*? Knowing for a fact, intellectually, that something is real, but doubting it anyway? Can you give more context?

Comment: Your sample sentence refers specifically to self-confidence and not just confidence. Are you looking for a word that refers specifically to self-doubt?

Comment: What do they doubt, the value of the goals or their ability to achieve them?

Comment: Your own term *doubt* seems to fit the bill. Is there any reason why you rejected it?

Answer (score 1):

If the doubt is irrational, then it’s **[imposter syndrome](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Impostor_syndrome)**:

> Impostor syndrome is a psychological pattern in which one doubts one's accomplishments and has a persistent internalized fear of being exposed as a "fraud".

This phrase can be directly inserted into your example sentence.

If there’s not an element of accomplishment involved I would just say it’s just **low self-esteem**.

Answer (score 0):

The nearest I can get is *inadequacy*

> a lack of confidence that makes someone feel they are not good enough to deal with a particular situation or with life in general
>
> [Macmillan dictionary](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/inadequacy)

Being a *feeling*, it is not rational. Being a lack of confidence, it inhibits the pursuit of goals.